# cant convert parameter from char[#] to LPWSTR

Tags: visual-c++

When I compile this code in Visual C++, I got the below error. Can help me solve this issue..

```
DWORD nBufferLength = MAX_PATH;
char szCurrentDirectory[MAX_PATH + 1];
GetCurrentDirectory(nBufferLength, szCurrentDirectory); 
szCurrentDirectory[MAX_PATH +1 ] = '\0';
```

Error message:

```
Error   5   error C2664: 'GetCurrentDirectoryW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [261]' to 'LPWSTR'  c:\car.cpp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is configured to be compiled as unicode. Thats why GetCurrentDirectory is GetCurrentDirectoryW, which expects a `LPWSTR` (`wchar_t*`).

GetCurrentDirectoryW expects a `wchar_t` instead of `char` array. You can do this using `TCHAR`, which - like GetCurrentDirectory - depends on the unicode setting and always represents the appropriate character type.

Don't forget to prepend your `'\0'` with an `L` in order to make the char literal unicode, too!

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have define `UNICODE, _UNICODE` compiler flags. In that case, you need to change the type of `szCurrentDirectory` from `char` to `TCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

**Headers:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h> //not sure
```

**Function to get current directory:**

```
std::string getCurrentDirectoryOnWindows()
{
    const unsigned long maxDir = 260;
    wchar_t currentDir[maxDir];
    GetCurrentDirectory(maxDir, currentDir);
    std::wstring ws(currentDir);
    std::string current_dir(ws.begin(), ws.end());
    return std::string(current_dir);
}
```

**To call function:**

```
std::string path = getCurrentDirectoryOnWindows(); //Output like: C:\Users\NameUser\Documents\Programming\MFC Program 5
```

**To make dir (Folder) in current directory:**

```
std::string FolderName = "NewFolder";
std::string Dir1 = getCurrentDirectoryOnWindows() + "\\" + FolderName;
_mkdir(Dir1.c_str());
```

This works for me in MFC C++.